# Get value from multioptions form in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

Let's suppose that I have this subform of a form:

```
$form->addElement('select','foo',
array(
    'label'        => 'ComboBox (select)',
    'value'        => 'blue',
    'multiOptions' => array(
        'red'    => 'Rouge',
        'blue'   => 'Bleu',
        'white'  => 'Blanc',
    ),
    )
);
```

How do I get the value from `multiOptions`?
I managed to get the array using,

```
$subForm = $form->getElement("foo");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getMultiOptions()` and `getMultiOption()` methods as shown below.

```
$form->getElement("foo")->getMultiOptions(); //Get all options

$form->getElement("foo")->getMultiOption('option'); //Get one option.
```

You can find more methods in the ZF documentation link below.

[ZF Multi select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect)